# Remove duplicate color declaration from body

Tags: bug, chat, design

The CSS for `chat.stackexchange.com` defines the following:

```
body{font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;color:#333;font-size:12px;background-color:#fdfdfd;color:#444444;}
```

It defines both `#333` and `#444444` as the color.

Comment: This is the so-called "Hex multiplication hack". It amounts to `#121212121212` which is Unicorn gold

Comment: Wouldn't that be a `[bug]`, actually? :)

Comment: Congratulations, you have found the most unexciting "bug" ever :)

Comment: Can we have a `[246-toothpicks]` tag for questions like this?

Comment: such a shame, we only had 48 more shades of gray to go before we were busted.

Comment: @balpha: Oh yeah, how about [this one](http://i.imgur.com/IL0iV.png)? ;)